# Added attribute in R not shown

Tags: r, attributes

Can I know why my added attribute "cum" not shown in ata.table although str(ata.table) shown that this item is in? Thanks.

```
library(ChainLadder)
dat<-data.frame(originf=factor(rep(1:10,10:1)),    
dev=sequence(10:1),inc_paid=c(
357848,766940,610542,482940,527326,574398,146342,139950,227229,67948,
352118,884021,933894,1183289,445745,320996,527804,266172,425046,
290507,1001799,926219,1016654,750816,146923,495992,280405,
310608,1108250,776189,1562400,272482,352053,206286,
443160,693190,991983,769488,504851,470639,
396132,937085,847498,805037,705960,
440832,847631,1131398,1063269,
359480,1061648,1443370,
376686,986608,
344014))

n<-10
(inc.triangle <- with(dat, {
M <- matrix(nrow=n, ncol=n,
dimnames=list(origin=levels(originf), dev=1:n))
M[cbind(originf, dev)] <- inc_paid
M
}))

cum.triangle <- incr2cum(inc.triangle)
ata.table<-ata(cum.triangle)            
cum.ldf<-attr(ata.table,"vwtd")
cum.ldf<-rev(cumprod(rev(cum.ldf)))

attr(ata.table,"cum")<-cum.ldf
```

Comment: This depends on the `print` method of the `ata.table` . Attributes can be invisible yet present

Comment: The same way you added `vwtd`.

Comment: the vwtd is standard in the ata function

Comment: `attr(ata.table,"cum")<-cum.ldf` is the code and its correct

Comment: You do not have to see it, but you could access it. ie `attr(ata.table,"cum")` is available

Comment: what do you mean by *show it*?

Comment: when i run ata.table , the attribute for cum is not shown. only vwtd and smpl is shown

Comment: When you print it, R uses the function `print.ata` which prints the object in a specific way. It does not look for "extra" attributes. You can use this hack to get the output to look like you want it to `ata.table; cat("  cum", round(cum.ldf, 3))`. The function used is `summary.ata` which you can find with `getAnywhere(summary.ata())`. You could edit that function to include 'cum`.

Comment: It is an attribute. in order to show it, you will have to write a print method for your ata table. Do not change the one given

Comment: Thanks. I will try to change the print method.